# Bind quick search to a Listview

Tags: android, search, listview

How can we bind a quick search to ListView? I mean when the search button on phone is pressed while in the ListView it should search ListView items.

Answer (score 0):

[Search Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html) doesn't work that way.

But it's not that complicated to build what you want. When you will have put everything in place to receive the query from the seach framework, then you could use it to build a new adapter for you listview, and pass it to the list view.

With CursorAdapter filtering can be achieved very easily in SQL.

Good reading,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

you should walk through this [Searchable Dictionary](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html)

Comment: Thanks Pragna ..I should have a look at it